# VB.NET concurrency violation error when updating an Access table

Tags: vb.net

Just to eliminate thing I created a simple example to reproduce the problem. 
In an MSaccess database I've got a table named 'tblTest' with an autoincrement field 'ID' and a string field named 'Test'. ID is primary key.

Now here's the code:

```
        Dim cmdSELECT As New OleDbCommand()
        Dim cmdUPDATE As New OleDbCommand()

        Dim Para As OleDbParameter
        Para = New OleDbParameter()
        Para.ParameterName = "@ID"
        Para.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer
        Para.SourceColumn = "ID"
        cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add(Para)

        Para = New OleDbParameter()
        Para.ParameterName = "@Test"
        Para.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar
        Para.Size = 255
        Para.SourceColumn = "Test"
        cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add(Para)

        Dim MyConnection As New OleDbConnection
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & AddSlash(Application.StartupPath) & "Connexis.accdb"
        MyConnection.Open()

        cmdSELECT.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTest"
        cmdSELECT.Connection = MyConnection
        cmdUPDATE.CommandText = "UPDATE tblTest SET Test = @Test WHERE ID = @ID"
        cmdUPDATE.Connection = MyConnection

        Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmdSELECT
        adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdUPDATE

        Dim DTtest As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(DTtest)
        DTtest(0)("Test") = "Testing 123"

        adapter.Update(DTtest)
```

The last line gives the error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.DBConcurrencyException' occurred in System.Data.dll

When I do an insert in a similar way, all works well.
Of course there are no other users what so ever.
What am I missing here?

A lot has been written about the error but I didn't find the answer yet...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, when using the Jet or ACE OLE DB providers, parameters are used based on their position.  You can certainly give the parameters names, as you have, but those names are not used to match parameters to placeholders in the SQL code.  This means that you must add the parameters to the `OleDbCommand` in the same order as they appear in the SQL code, which you are not.  `@Test` appears before `@ID` in the SQL code so you need to change this:

```
Dim Para As OleDbParameter
Para = New OleDbParameter()
Para.ParameterName = "@ID"
Para.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer
Para.SourceColumn = "ID"
cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add(Para)

Para = New OleDbParameter()
Para.ParameterName = "@Test"
Para.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar
Para.Size = 255
Para.SourceColumn = "Test"
cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add(Para)
```

to this:

```
Para = New OleDbParameter()
Para.ParameterName = "@Test"
Para.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar
Para.Size = 255
Para.SourceColumn = "Test"
cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add(Para)

Dim Para As OleDbParameter
Para = New OleDbParameter()
Para.ParameterName = "@ID"
Para.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer
Para.SourceColumn = "ID"
cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add(Para)
```

Actually, in the interests of not writing unnecessarily convoluted code, you should change it to this:

```
cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add("@Test", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, "Test")
cmdUPDATE.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "ID")
```

EDIT:

I should also point out exactly why this generates a concurrency violation.  Concurrency exceptions have a specific legitimate purpose: to detect the situation where saving the current user's changes would clash with changes that another user has made in the meantime.

Consider a situation where user A retrieves data and then user B retrieves the same data.  User B makes a change to column 1 in a record and then saves their changes.  User A makes a change to column 2 in the same record and then tries to save their changes.  In a "last in wins" scenario, user A's data would be saved and that would replace the new value in column 1 that was saved by user B with the original value that was still in the record saved by user A, thus wiping out user B's changes.  That would be considered bad my most people.

Using "optimistic concurrency", when user A tries to save their changes, the system compares the original data for the record(s) being saved with the data currently in the database.  If they match then no changes have been made by other users and the changes are saved.  If they don't match, a concurrency violation occurs and ADO.NET throws an exception.  It's up to you, as the developer, to catch that exception and perform the appropriate action(s).  That generally means retrieving the data currently in the database and either replacing the data you have with that or else merging the two.  The user should then review the data again, make any additional changes they consider appropriate and then save again.

The reason that that method is known as "optimistic concurrency" is that it hopes for the best, i.e. allows users to retrieve and use the same data at the same time, but plans for the worst, i.e. makes sure that multiple changes to that data don't interfere with each other.  The third option is "pessimistic concurrency", which assumes the worst and won't let multiple users retrieve the same data in the first place.  That is usually done using row- or table-level locks.